# "As people at all levels of French society began to feel more of a stake..."

Tags: sentence-construction

> As people at all levels of French society began to feel more of a stake
>   in France's future, the power of the masses was starting to be tapped
>   unlike ever before in history.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/napoleonic/context.html

Wouldn't it better if it was written  in a way as below ?

As people at all levels of French society began to feel (of ) more (that) 
  France's future is AT stake, the power of the masses was starting to be tapped
 unlike ever before in history.

Answer (score 6):

The sentence is awkward. A stake is not something which can be felt. I think the author got a little muddled while writing  the words *feel* and *stake*, and never went back and tidied the sentence up.

In this context, a *stake* is, broadly, something which is put forward as a wager. When we we speak of something being *at stake* means that it is in some sense *at risk* of being lost.

However, I don't think the author means that more and more people felt that   France's future was *at stake*, that the future looked dangerous for France. I think, rather, that the *in* in that sentence is what the author intended, and that what he is trying to say is that more and more people

> felt they ***had*** a stake **in** France's future—

that is, that what was *at stake* in the 'wager' on France's future was their *own* property or happiness, that they themselves stood to win or lose according as France succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 2):

No, your rephrasing changed the meaning.  The "stake" refers to the masses *having a stake in* France's future (an interest or share in an undertaking or enterprise)

see http://i.word.com/idictionary/stake [noun] sense 3(c)

The only fixes the sentence needs are an "a" before "stake", and a "the" before "masses".